# Sub panel supplied by two different lines from main panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I looked but couldn't find this asked already.
I found a sub panel in the crawl space of my home.  It looks to supply an upstairs addition.
It has 2 different 14/2 cables going into it from the main panel, each on a 15 amp breaker.
Inside the sub panel are a 15 and 20 amp breaker, with the 20 amp connected to 12/2 running up to the addition and 14/2 on the 15 amp.
My best guess is this was done to get 20 amps up to the bathroom by "splitting" the current over the 2 lines supplying the sub panel.
Is this even legal?
I could probably replace the existing 14/2 going into the sub panel with 12/2, but I'm not sure that is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the main panel and the subpanel?

Comment: #14 feeder should not be supplying a subpanel, since it's only good for 15A and that is pointless.  It cannot power anything 20A.  The usual purpose of using dual /2 is to bring up both legs of hot and also neutral, this is the wrong way to do that.  If you replace it, use something like 10/3.  The 10 solves the ampacity problem and the /3 solves the split-cables problem.

Comment: In addition, most jurisdictions do not allow panels, sub or not, to be located in areas with restricted access like a crawl space. So you cannot legally do anything to that because it is an illegal installation to start with.

Comment: Can you post photos of the main panel and the subpanel?

Answer (score 2):

Either it's 120V subpanel and he's plain paralleling... which is rather bad.

Or it's a 240V panel, and he's supplying hot/neutral/ground with one cable and the other hot with the other cable.  That's a different kind of bad.

Both are unacceptable.  You should replace both cables with a single /3 cable:

- 4/3 Aluminum or 6/3 Copper if you want 60A in this subpanel
- 8/3 Copper if you want 40A
- 10/3 if you want 30A
- 12/3 if you want 20A
- 14/3 if you want 15A, but this is fairly pointless.

And, both hot wires need to land on a 2-pole breaker **which has common trip**, meaning both legs trip together, and, move either handle, the other goes too.

[image]

Note that a [duplex/tandem/twin/double-stuff](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc) has independent handles and must not be used, as it will create a dangerous situation if you do.